# Formula Result in Function Argument Window Different Than in Cell

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I have the following array formula:

```
=MAX(COUNTIF(Sheet2!A$2:Sheet2!A$6,Sheet2!A2:Sheet2!A6))
```

Which is supposed to give me the count of duplicate entries in a small text column in a worksheet. I've put one duplicate entry to test the formula, and the result I should get is **2**. Instead, once I ctrl+enter, the cell shows **0**. However, when I click the formula button next to the cell content field, it shows **Formula result = 2**.

Calculation Options are set to Automatic (this is Excel 2010), and I have no idea why this is happening. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: BTW the formula gives you a count of the largest number of identical cells, which is only the same as the count of duplicate entries when there is only one value that is duplicated.

Comment: Yeah, I am using it to show that duplication occurred, more than actually give the exact number of duplicates (which would need an array if there is more than one duplicate I believe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it was a keyboard problem with the shift or ctrl buttons stuck (: I clicked on the formula inside the formula argument window, then clicked ctrl+shift+enter and it added the curly brackets for the array formula and the result is now correct and updates correctly when the source data changes.